# JS to force input button to be clicked when the page has been loaded

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, forms, refresh

I have an input button which needs to be clicked automatically when the page loads. I have the following input button code:

```
<form enctype="multipart/form-data" name="cart" action="cart.php#order_statistics" method="POST">               
   <table id="order_statistics">
      echo '<td><button type="submit" id="refreshCart" style="border: none; background: none; cursor: pointer;" name="clicked" value="Update Order"><img src="images/refresh.png" alt="Refresh Image"/></button></td>';
   </table>
</form>
```

I have tried several other ways of doing this but to no avail. When I tried other ways of doing this, the script I used would press the button automatically but the page would keep refreshing and would be on a constant looping refresh.

I don't know if it may be because of the action in the form tag?

Any help would be appreciated.

My page (cart.php) code can be found [here](http://pastebin.com/PeCp6mdG)

Comment: Have you tried inserting the function on the $(document).ready? so that when the user end up on that form, it will automatically trigger the function?

Answer (score 0):

change your form to

```
<form enctype="multipart/form-data" name="cart" action="cart.php#order_statistics" method="POST">               
   <table id="order_statistics">
      echo '<td><button id="refreshCart" style="border: none; background: none; cursor: pointer;" name="clicked" value="Update Order"><img src="images/refresh.png" alt="Refresh Image"/></button></td>';
      echo '<td><button type="submit" style="border: none; background: none; cursor: pointer;" name="clicked" value="Place order Order"><img src="images/Place order.png" alt="Place order Image"/></button></td>';
   </table>
</form>
```

add this command to your script.

```
$("#refreshCart").trigger("click");
```

check out [trigger()](http://api.jquery.com/trigger/) function.

Comment: Hi there, thanks for your comment. I have tried this however the page just ends up refreshing itself over and over and over again on an endless loop. Would you like me to post my entire page for you?

Comment: remove  _type="submit"_ from your button it is submitting your form as its a submit button.

Comment: I have just tried this, it still just keep refreshing in an endless loop. I can post the code if you would like?

Answer (score 0):

With jQuery:

```
$(window).load(function() {
    $('#refreshCart').click();
});
```

Or native JavaScript:

```
window.onload = function() {
  document.getElementById('refreshCart').click();
};
```

To avoid the infinite loop did you comment, you need to change the submit by an [AJAX request](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.post/):

```
$(window).load(function() {
    $.ajax({
        url: "/your_form.php",
        type: "post",
        data: your_data
    });
});
```

Comment: Hi there, thanks for your comment. With your code I encounter the same issue as when I try the code posted below by Vikram Sangat. The page just ends up refreshing itself over and over and over again on an endless loop. Would you like me to post my entire page for you?

Answer (score 0):

I believe what you want to do is submit your form by clicking the button,
So I would suggest you programmatically submit the form with this.

Approach1 :

```
document.cart.submit();
```

Approach2: Give a Id to your form and then

```
document.getElementById('giveSomeIdToForm').submit();
```

Also, to programmatically click the button,

```
document.getElementById('refreshCart').click();
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your comment. This however has the same issues as above. The cart just keeps refreshing on an endless loop. Would you like me to paste my entire page code?

Comment: It might be because. the page where you are inserting this code happens to be cart.php. So whenever you submit a form it tends to hit the url in the action attribute, which will again submit the form programmatically and this leads to a infinite loop. Am I right ?

Comment: Yes I think that's correct. The "Action" of the form is the same page which is cart.php

Comment: Yeah. so maybe what you want to do is. Keep the action attribute pointing to a different php meant to do the logic. Or if possible add an extra parameter in the URL while submitting the form. All this I can only comment on if I know the exact reason for this auto submission we are doing

Comment: What happens is, when I add a product to the cart, the cart doesn't load the products unless the submit button is clicked. We're trying to find either a solution or a way around it. Please see my entire page code here: http://pastebin.com/PeCp6mdG

Comment: Ok but that is when someone adds something in the cart. But why do we want to programmatically submit when the page has loaded?

Comment: The reason for pressing this button is because we're taking an order_id from a $_SESSION cookie and getting the contents of that single ID, such as the quantity, price etc. without clicking this button, the code to do this does not run.